# problem with eqnarray

Tags: math-mode

Would you like to help me please i'm a beginner !
what's wrong with my code?

```
{\setlength{\jot}{0.40 cm}

\begin{eqnarray*}

 n^*_{11} & = & \dfrac{n_{1.}\times n_{.1}}{n} \\

& =  & \dfrac{120 \times 120}{200}     \\          

\text{avec}   \quad \sum_{k=1}^{q} n^*_{jk}  &  =  &  n_{j.}   \quad \text{ et}  \quad   \sum_{j=1}^{p} n^*_{jk}   = n_{.k}   \\

    n^*_{jk}   & =   & \dfrac{120\times 120}{200}  \\

  n^*_{12}   & =   & \dfrac{n_{1.}\times n_{.2}}{n} \\

  &                  =    &  \dfrac{120\times 80}{200}  \\

  n^*_{21}  &  =         &  \dfrac{n_{2.}\times n_{.1}}{n}  \\

  n^*_{21}  & =   &   \dfrac{60\times 120}{200} \\$$

\end{eqnarray*}}
```

thank you

Comment: Remove all the empty lines. Remove the closing `\\$$`. Add `\documentclass{article}` and `\usepackage{amsmath}` and `\begin{document}` at the top. Add `\end{document}` at the bottom.

Comment: While you're at it, replace every `{eqnarray*}` with either `{align}` or `{align*}`, and remove the `&` characters which follow your `=` signs. (Don't use `eqnarray`, it's not very good!)

Comment: my code with documentclass begin and a

Answer (score 7):

Your error is in the spurious `$$`. But don't use `eqnarray`. Never ever.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
n^*_{11} & = \frac{n_{1{\cdot}}\times n_{{\cdot}1}}{n} \\
         & = \frac{120 \times 120}{200}     \\
\text{avec} \quad \sum_{k=1}^{q} n^*_{jk}  &  =  n_{j{\cdot}}
  \quad \text{et}  \quad   \sum_{j=1}^{p} n^*_{jk}   = n_{.k}   \\
n^*_{jk} & = \frac{120\times 120}{200}  \\
n^*_{12} & = \frac{n_{1{\cdot}}\times n_{{\cdot}2}}{n} \\
         & = \frac{120\times 80}{200}  \\
n^*_{21} & = \frac{n_{2{\cdot}}\times n_{{\cdot}1}}{n}  \\
n^*_{21} & = \frac{60\times 120}{200}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Increasing the line spacing is not required.

[image]